# delete an image from media folder

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, magento-1.8, adminhtml, database

Is there any method to delete files in magento? I have a custom module using which I can upload images to the folder media. Now I am planning to provide a delete option under each uploaded images(uploaded images will display in my module). When delete option clicked, it should delete images from media folder and its name from the custom table

```
custom table name : banner
custom field name for storing image names :  images
         (names are separated by commas)
module : custom admin module use to upload multiple images
module model name : banner/banner
```

Is it really necessary to delete images from media folder. Please provide your suggestions. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your question about whether or not it's good policy to clean up images if unused or on how to build an extension like this?

Comment: @SanderMangel:yes. exactly. I want to know whether it is essential to delete unused images in magento. However I need to remove the name of unused image from magento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Magento is based on PHP, there is a method to delete files: `unlink` ;-)

Beside of this very basic method I can't find any class in Magento or the attached Zend_Framework which offers a file abstraction.

Comment: Is magento using `unlink` for deleting images then? In other words, how unwanted files are manipulating by magento?

Comment: In the end? Yes `@unlink($fullPath);`, `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/File/Storage/File.php:122` but most of the time magento doesn't delete anything, e.g. images from media folder.

Comment: when should we think about deleting images then? which are the specific cases, where deletion is better than leaving the unwanted images?

Comment: I only know one case: When you get copyright problems

Comment: :Thanks it will help me a lot. Thanks for your explanation.